# Not getting proper data, when I declare scope as @RequestScoped in JSF

Tags: jsf

In my ManagedBean class, I am getting the session value in my init(`@PostConstruct`) Method like

```
int sessionTargetId = (int) context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("targetId");
```

Here my problem is, I have two users when I declared scope as `@SessionScoped` at my class level for the first user I am getting proper data. when I click on second user for the first time I am getting previous session data(getting first user data only). The `init()` method is not called every time.

When I declared scope as `@RequestScoped` at my class level, I am not getting the data here the `init()` method is called every time but I am unable to display data (when I debugged it the process will going correctly)

Can any one plz tell me what I need to do to get correct data?

Comment: I do by far not understand the concrete question you want to ask. What do you mean to say by "*proper data*"? Presumably it appears that you are trying to verify session info just by using a single client. Try reviewing info of different users held by session scoped beans (as decorated by `@SessionScoped`) using different clients (different browsers). You should be able to see what you think/expect.

Comment: Proper Data means which i am getting from db.when i declared as @SessionScoped i am getting same first user data for second user also.In my init(@PostConstruct) method i am getting session value.But it is calling only first time so it uses first user id only

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating it by a practical example(s). At least, I cannot imagine what is going on there in your application. (a method decorated by `@PostConstruct` in a session scoped bean is invoked only once per user session. Thus it is not invoked on every single HTTP request, by the way).